# Presenting crosstabs in addition to multinominal logistic regression results (SPSS)

Tags: regression, logistic, multiple-regression, spss

I'm using multinominal logistic regression (MLR) in SPSS to build a predictive model to identify which variables have an independent effect on an outcome, all things being equal.

I then want to use crosstabs to pinpoint and discuss where exactly any differences lie between the statistically significant explanatory variables by comparing column proportions, particularly as I feel crosstabs results are more accessible and visually interpretable than MLR.

My question is: is it acceptable practice to use and present both MLR and crosstab results in this way?

Answer (score 0):

This is really only possible to do in particular instances, not in general designs, without distorting what the logistic regression analysis is indicating.